# Допустимо ли использовать пустую инструкцию в IF? Или это плохая практика?

Tags: php

```
if ($a == 'a' || $a == 'b') {
}
else if ($a == 'c' || $a == 'd' || $a == 'e' || $a == 'f' || $a == 'g' || $a == 'h') {
    $a = 'b';
}
else {
    $a = 'a';
}
```

Comment: Это индокод -- код ради количества строк, а не ради выполнения конкретной задачи.

Answer (score 2):

Так лучше не делать, обычно в таких случаях достаточно переписать условие.

```
if (in_array($a, ['3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'])) {
    $a = '2';
}
elseif ($a != '1' && $a != '2') {
    $a = '1';
}
```

Вот так выглядит лучше и понятней, а результат тот же.

Comment: не поверите, это и есть реальный пример

Comment: @Khipster не проблема, в ответ добавил свой вариант.

Comment: прошу прощения, но это не цифры, а строки. т.е. в оригинале там слова.

Comment: @Khipster отредактировал ответ, не сразу ваш комментарий понял верно

Answer (score 1):

Если есть условие - значит есть ветвление.
Пустое тело ветви - признак нафиг не нужности условия.

В данном случае *может* поможет `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё не много сократить код, если сохранить строки в массив, и организовать поиск по массиву функцией *array_search()* с помощью тернарного оператора

```
$a = 'b'; // Искомая строка
$arr = ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']; // Допустимые значения
$a = (array_search($a, $arr)  !== false ? 'b' : 'a');

echo $a;// Вывод "a"
```